# How to make a POST request with an array in body data

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, http-post

I'm trying to do this with Objective-C but i think is the same body data but a don't know how it has to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to do this:

```
POST request
head: </*Your route*/>
body:

p=aString&p=bString&p=cString&p=dString
```

And then in the server you get:

```
body : {
     p : [{
          "aString",
          "bString",
          "cString",
          "dString"
     }]
}
```

Thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 0):

One way (not sure the best way) is to encode the array in the POST data by sending the # of elements as a POST data field.  For example

```
NSArray *array = @[@"hi", @"there"];

NSMutableString *postData = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"array_length=%d", array.count];
for (int i=0; i<array.count; ++i)
    [postData appendFormat:@"&array_%d=%@", i, array[i]];

// ...
```

The decoder, then, takes `array_length` and iterates over `i = [0 .. array_length-1]` to repopulate the array with `array_0, array_1, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods I used in an old project. You'll need to set the NSURLConnectionDelegate and implement the required methods.

```
// Check if the URLString is a valid data object
- (void) formatURLString: (NSString *) target forData:(NSArray *) data 
{
    if ([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:data]) 
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSData *JSONdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        // *** POST ***//
        [self post:target withJSON:JSONdata];
    } else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid JSON object. JSON object: %@", data);
    }
}


- (void) post: (NSString *) target withJSON: (NSData *) jsonData 
{
    // Inform user network activity is taking place
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest =
    [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:target]];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"METHOD"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                                  delegate:self];
    if (!connection) { NSLog(@"Connection Failed"); }
}
```